# Int object has no attribute round

Tags: python, pandas

Hy all!
I'm new in python and I faced a problem. I'm working in a pandas data frame,  use the description function to get some descriptive statistics about the data frame and use the round function to get the results rounded it is works well, but if I want to use the round function along with the mean function I got an error.
Here is the code: **ratings['rating'].mean().round(2)**

The error is **AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'round'**

Can you explain why it is not working?
Thanks

Comment: use `round(ratings['rating'].mean(), 2)`

Comment: @usr2564301: Wrong documentation. Try [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) instead.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: sorry – the error message is exactly the same...

Comment: I think there's an issue here that isn't covered well by the marked duplicates: that of distinguishing between dealing with a Pandas `Series` versus dealing with a single value.